# How do I say that someone lives in a place that is away from the current place?

Tags: phrase-requests

Here's the sentence I want to say : My parents stayed at my sister's for a few days before returning/leaving _________.

With returning, I could say 'home' or 'to their place', but that does not convey that they're not from around here.

With leaving, I could say 'town' or just the name of the current place, but I want a general way of conveying it. What if I don't want to name the place, or it is the country side, not town?

I'm not committed to using returning/leaving. Suggestions that remove these words altogether are welcome too.

Edit: To rephrase, I'm looking for a way for out-of-towners to say that they're going back.

Comment: "Returning home" or "going home" doesn't seem to me to carry the implication that home is "around here".

Comment: 'going back home' probably connotes distance better.

Comment: @KateBunting Neither does it say that home is NOT around here. I'm looking for a way to say just that.

Comment: My parents stayed at my sister's, away from their hometown, for a few days before returning home.

Comment: I think you’re trying to combine too many disparate elements. For instance while personally of course it does, grammatically and largely semantically, whether anyone stayed at your sister’s, or in a hotel or on the street can’t be relevant; nor can the duration.

Isn’t *they* stayed at/in *location* before returning/leaving… much more clear?

Either way *leaving* ignores the destination except in the sense of *leaving for*, which would indeed match *returning*.

Grammatically it can’t matter whether you say *town* or the name of the place and where did *just* come from, please?

More…

Comment: To me, that seems the other way round. *The name of the place, or just ’town’*.

Almost certainly there is no general way of conveying it, as shown by your contrasting place name, countryside or town… which suggests it’s not a way for out-of-towners to say anything.

Comment: One obvious compromise might be to use a verb like *trek/slog/hike* or even *journey/travel* and of which to an extent implies the journey was long in distance or time, or arduous, or some combination of the three.

Answer (score 2):

"Traveling home" seems to convey that they had to make an effort or go a good distance to get home. Along with that, "journeying home" might also be a good fit, perhaps even more so than traveling as it gives off a feeling of being more effort to make the trip home.